# Multiply arrays representing integers (Similar to BigInteger)?

Tags: java, for-loop, multiplication

Basically, the integer array (named digits of class BigInteger) is used to represent a single large integer. Up to this point, I have solved how to add-with-carry two of the arrays and also subtract-with-carry, but multiplication is giving me problems. Below is the code I have written:

```
public BigInteger multiply(BigInteger n) {
    int carry = 0;

        for(int i = n.digits.length - 1; i >= 0;i--) {

            for(int j = this.digits.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

                int val = (this.digits[i] * n.digits[j]) + carry;
                this.digits[i] = val % 10;
                carry = val / 10;
            }

        }//for
        return this;
    }
```

This code works as long as the invoking `this` is larger and the parameter `n` is a single digit. But as soon as `n` exceeds 1 digit, the code fails. I am at a loss, and guidance in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: "...the code fails..." is unacceptable. You must clearly state in what way it fails.

Comment: You have to add all the units together, then add all the tens together (there is two of them) then add all the products which make hundreds together (there could be 3 of them) etc. Try doing this by hand so you know what you need to do in code.

Comment: Okay, thank you Peter. And sorry James, I thought that was clear enough. It produces zero every time, but don't worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

`for(int j = this.digits.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {`

with

`for(int j = this.digits.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {`

You don't want to decrement `i` while iterating through the inner loop. After you make this correction, you should be good to go.